# Remove File and value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

May I ask about how can I remove the value of `q` , when the class `.close` is clicked?
Here with my source code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parents('p').remove();

})

$('#Q1DocPath').change(function () {

    var path = $(this).val();

    if (path != '' && path != null) {
        var q = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

        $('#lblQ1Doc').html('<br/>' + '<p>' + q + '<a class="close"><font color="red">x</font><a>' + '</p>');

    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need to remove the value of `q` only from HTML.
The easiest way is to wrap the value with the `span` tag.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).prev('span').remove();

})

$('#Q1DocPath').change(function () {

    var path = $(this).val();

    if (path != '' && path != null) {
        var q = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

        $('#lblQ1Doc').html('<br/>' + '<p><span>' + q + '</span><a class="close"><font color="red">x</font><a>' + '</p>');

    }
})
```

Let me know if you needed something else or injected HTML can't be modified, I'll correct the answer.

Comment: if the #lblQ1Doc had use the session ?

Comment: What do you mean “use the session”?

Comment: because previously I had set the #lblQ1Doc with session

Comment: I do not quite understand, do you mean window.sessionStorage? Or what session could be in Javascript?

Comment: window.sessionStorage

Comment: What was stored in the sessionStorage? How did the element use it? You'd better post the code here

Comment: I create another questions at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655100/file-upload-control-session-does-not-remove-after-remove-file-from-list

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, having read [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655100/file-upload-control-session-does-not-remove-after-remove-file-from-list), you have stored some data in the [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) using C#.

And now you want to remove that same data from within the browser using Javascript ?

If so, what you want to use is[<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Storage):

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('key_to_your_data');
```